# Transfer data from server to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

I need to transfer data from a external server to my host using servlet. Instead of uploading file i need to download from another server.
I tried normal download java program but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

`in servlet` you can get the file from a specific `URL` and send it to client like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException, UnavailableException
    {

        int bytesRead = 0;
        int count = 0;
        byte[] buff = new byte[1];

        OutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();

        res.setContentType("application/contenttype");//i.e: contenttype=pdf,doc,etc" );

        String fileURL = "http://someaddress/somefile.someextension";
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

        res.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                      "attachment; filename=somefile.someextension;");

        URL url = new URL(fileURL);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        while (-1 != (bytesRead = bis.read(buff, 0, buff.length)))
            {
                bos.write(bytesRead);
                bos.flush();

            }
    }
```

Note: you need to handle the related exceptions also.

Comment: i need to download file into my server from a remote server not to the client machine